# Android Data Binding Problem: Missing return statement in generated code while using with a custom view?

Tags: android, kotlin, android-databinding

I am using data binding in my current application, and so far so good. However, when I tried to use it with a custom data binding adapter I wrote for my custom view, I got an error from auto generated file as the title says, missing return statement. This error does not occur when I used this data binding on only one view, but more than one gives the error. Below are my custom view and adapters, and usage in xml file. I already checked the answer of kinda duplicated question but it doesn't worked in my case, and does not have enough explanation.

```
class NeonTextView(context: Context, attrs: AttributeSet) : TextView(context, attrs) {

private val drawableClear: Drawable?
    get() = ContextCompat.getDrawable(context, R.drawable.ic_clear)

lateinit var actionMethod: () -> Unit
lateinit var clearMethod: () -> Unit
var hasActionMethod = false
var hasClearMethod = false

init {
    setupAttributes(attrs)
}

private fun setupAttributes(attrs: AttributeSet) {
    val typedArray =
        context.theme.obtainStyledAttributes(attrs, R.styleable.NeonTextView, 0, 0)

    hasActionMethod = typedArray.getBoolean(
        R.styleable.NeonTextView_hasActionMethod,
        false
    )
    hasClearMethod = typedArray.getBoolean(
        R.styleable.NeonTextView_hasClearMethod,
        false
    )
    typedArray.recycle()
}

override fun onTextChanged(
    text: CharSequence?,
    start: Int,
    lengthBefore: Int,
    lengthAfter: Int
) {
    text?.let { text ->
        drawableClear?.let {
            it.setBounds(0, 0, it.intrinsicWidth, it.intrinsicHeight)
        }
        setCompoundDrawablesWithIntrinsicBounds(
            null,
            null,
            if (text.isNotEmpty()) drawableClear!! else null,
            null
        )
    }
}

override fun onTouchEvent(event: MotionEvent?): Boolean {
    event?.let {
        return when (it.action) {
            ACTION_DOWN -> return true
            ACTION_UP -> {
                if (compoundDrawables[2] == null && hasActionMethod) {
                    actionMethod()
                } else {
                    if (it.x > (width - paddingRight - compoundDrawables[2]!!.intrinsicWidth)) {
                        if (hasClearMethod) clearMethod()
                        text = ""
                    } else {
                        if (hasActionMethod) actionMethod()
                    }
                }
                performClick()
                true
            }
            else -> false
        }
    }.run {
        return false
    }
}

override fun performClick(): Boolean {
    super.performClick()
    return true
}
}
```

And here is my binding adapters for binding methods that are used inside this custom text view:

```
@BindingAdapter("actionMethod")
fun NeonTextView.setActionMethod(actionMethod: () -> Unit) {
    this.actionMethod = actionMethod
    this.hasActionMethod = true
}

@BindingAdapter("clearMethod")
fun NeonTextView.setClearMethod(clearMethod: () -> Unit) {
    this.clearMethod = clearMethod
    this.hasClearMethod = true
}
```

And here is how I applied inside xml file:

```
<com.android.platform.NeonTextView
                        android:id="@+id/textViewSectionField"
                        style="@style/HeaderTextView.SubHeader"
                        app:hasActionMethod="true"
                        app:actionMethod="@{() -> viewModel.getDepartmentList()}"/>
```

Any ideas why I am getting error from generated file when I used this binding in more than one view inside xml?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2):

The problem is with Java<->Kotlin compatibility. In Kotlin if you declare function

```
interface Func {
    fun test(): Unit {
    }
}
```

And use it from java

```
class FuncImpl implements Func {
    @Override
    public Unit test() {
        return Unit.INSTANCE;
    }
}
```

Note, please, that in that case in java code you need **`return`** statement. The same is for lambdas.
So when you set up lambda from xml using databinding, it's treated as java's lambda, so generated code wasn't correctly processed in that case.

Comment: So is there a way to handle the approach currently I am trying? Or is it just a dead end, which needs to be handled by code?

Comment: Can you show source code of `viewModel.getDepartmentList()` function?

Comment: it calls following piece of code: private fun executeQuery(token: String, query: String) {
        sqlQueryUseCase(SqlQueryUseCase.Params(token, query)) {
            it.either(::handleErrorState, ::onDataListFetched)
        }
    } which one is a network call to a REST api, and retrieve the list from response and set to a MutableLiveData on view model itself.

Comment: So, as I understand, signature of method is `fun getDepartmentList(): Unit`. Is that right?

Comment: Can't reproduce your issue. I've copied all stuff from question, but have no errors. Am I missing something?

Comment: yep, its signature is as you stated, Unit. For some reason tough, on my side, when I tried it, it gave me the error. Probably something related with my project setup, I will try it with blank project to see what is going on.